# How to change style of all html elements in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i want to change the style of all elements in single line in js can you prefer any solution for that

I have tried :-

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.color='white';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.querySelectorAll('*')`

```js
changeColor = () => document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((node) => node.style.color='white');
```

```css
* {
    color: green;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: @Ouroborus can I know whats the issue with this answer?

Comment: Part of the request is that it be a one-liner.

Comment: @Ouroborus my function was easily updatable to onliner. I have updated my answer as oneline now. You can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate (loop) over them like this

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach((element) => {
  element.style.color = 'white'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to set the style of elements by CSS. When selecting all elements by Javascript and setting style for each, your browser has much work. In my code I get the `parent` id and add a class to control the CSS style of all child elements.

Check out this:

```js
$("#parent").addClass("color-red");
```

```css
#parent.color-red > *{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">

<div>Content 1</div>
<ul>
  <li>Content 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>

  <li>Content 2</li>

</ul>
<p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that if some elements have their color style set 'further down', inline for example, their color won't get changed as the setting in the parent will get overridden..

Comment: Even If set `!important` to `.red-color`?

Comment: Yes if the inline style of a element is also set to important it will override it. This may in some circumstances be what is wanted, but not in this question.